# Overnight loss of reputation

Tags: support, bug, reputation

I have a similar problem to the one highlighted in this [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21052/two-different-reputations). My reputation was 1037 yesterday but today its showing 971. Any ideas why this might me? I would like an explanation of why I lost reputation-I have been made to understand this is not due to deletion of posts.

Comment: Check the "show removed posts" box at the bottom of the reputation tab on your profile. Two questions you answered were deleted overnight, and you lost the reputation for those answers.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I see. Thanks for helping to solve this conundrum. I suppose the question is why were they deleted? Oh well, nothing I can do about that.

Comment: Its a bit a strange that every single reputation accrued from yesterday just got deleted. Is this deliberate? Can we find out who deleted those posts?

Comment: There's definitely something strange going on here. Other people who posted on the same posts that got deleted didn't lose their reputation score. I seem to be the only one who lost reputation. Can we hear from the moderators please. This needs further investigation.

Comment: On the one question, you were the only user who had reputation changes at all. On the other, the asker got back some reputation from the deletion, but I think you cannot see those events in their profile, only moderators and the profile owner can see it, iirc. Anyway, both posts [from the beginning of July] were deleted by three 10k users who judged that the site would be better off with the question removed.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation.

Comment: Of course, the 10k users in question might have been wrong. If you give us enough information to find the posts, then other 10k users can have a look and maybe decide to undelete the questions.

Comment: @John, meh. I've gotten used to it. I wake up every morning with about 50 or so rep lost from deleted questions. *shrugs*

Comment: So my question, why did I lose 66 reps-somebody must have instigated this.

Comment: When you check the aforementioned checkbox it will not show ***only*** the remove posts. It will show all the reputation changes and *also* show the removed posts. You can identify which posts were removed because (1) the reputation is negative; (2) it says "removed". (Also no one but you and the moderators can view your removed posts, so there's no point in linking other people to your reputation log.)

Comment: @Zain Patel, thanks. This is not the first time it's happening. But this one was just shocking!

Comment: @JonasMeyer, It is not a duplicate of the above.

Comment: Due to my acute skills (being able to click every link in a list), I found the two deleted questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1349008 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1349388. Everyone can judge the questions that were deleted now.

Comment: John, it is a duplicate. As @Daniel Fischer verified, you have lost reputation from two deleted posts.

Comment: @Najib: Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough. I really didn't want to make a fuss of this.

Comment: As far as this meta goes, this wasn't a fuss. Don't worry about it.

Comment: "I have been made to understand this is not due to deletion of posts." How?  See Daniel Fischer's first comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't even locate the deleted posts. @Jonas Meyer, see Asaf karagila's earlier post-"Absolutely none of the posts you linked were deleted. –  Asaf Karagila 26 mins ago".

Comment: John, you linked to irrelevant posts, which Asaf pointed out there.  See Najib's comment above for links to the deleted posts.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer, it says "page not found" when I clicked on those links.

Comment: They are only visible to users with more than 10k reputation, @John. If it helps, they were answers to questions titled "How to master mathematics from the scratch?" and "general solution to trigonometric equation, help!!!".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, thanks for that. I'll just focus on enjoying the maths rather than getting obsessed with reputation-its only a number after all.